# How to bind "Caps Lock" key event in Perl Tk?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to bind the "Caps Lock" key event in Perl Tk?

It looks like the key press is a keyboard hardware event, causing the keyboard to send ASCII codes for upper case letters, and not an OS feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Tk;


    my $mw = MainWindow->new;
    my $label = $mw->Label();
    $mw->geometry("200x200+50+50");

    $mw->bind('<Caps_Lock>' => \&exit);
    MainLoop;
```

UPDATE: You can check the keycodes and state:

```
    $mw->bind('<Caps_Lock>' =>  sub { capslock($mw)});
```

and define a function of that name:

```
    sub capslock
    {
      my ($mw) = shift;
      printf("keycode %d\n", $Tk::event->k);
      printf("state %d\n", $Tk::event->s);
    }
```

On Linux: The keycode is 66 and the state is 0 or 2 depending on whether set or not. For Windows: See my comment below.

UPDATE2: You can't complain about the service :) -
this will print the keycode and state on the label instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
my $codes = '';
my $label = $mw->Label(-font => ['courier', '12'],
    -justify => 'left',-textvariable => \$codes)->pack;
$mw->geometry("200x200+50+50");
$mw->bind('<Caps_Lock>' =>  sub { capslock($mw)});
MainLoop;

sub capslock
{
  my ($mw) = @_;

  $codes = sprintf("keycode %d\nstate %d",
    $Tk::event->k, $Tk::event->s);
}
```

Comment: I tried your example and still , nothing is printed. i am using a Microsoft keyboard, Can that make the difference?

Comment: It prints it in the DOS box that opens when you execute the program. I have just tested it on a Windows machine. However, it is state 8 and 10 on Windows and the keycode is 20.  I live and learn! :)

Comment: This might explain, as i am running Linux and connecting via Xconnect. Have you tested your code on Linux machine?

Comment: Oh, yes, I only use Debian Linux for development. I do have a Windows machine but it is really only used for PhotoShop. :)  On Linux the text shows in the terminal.

Comment: See my latest update above which prints the codes on the label instead. Apologies (well, not really :) for the global variable.

Comment: NirMH, please confirm that you can see the keycode and state on the graphic Tk Label in the latest version. If not, you have a very interesting problem that I would like to look into.

Comment: Sorry, i still don't see anything printed or displayed. I believe this is somehow related to my keyboard and the "Caps Lock" event is not actually sent to the OS. while testing my keyboard on a windows system, i do get the event fired.

Comment: Weird. I have tested my solution on several Linux systems and Windows. Like I wrote above, the solution with printing to the terminal/DOS box works fine as (of course) does the graphics text on the Tk label.